# Im making an animation studio/viewer with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, animation

Okay, so im making an animation thing where you like can wiew built-in animations or make your own, and this is the code so far:

```
import time
def bi2():
    print """\ \ \    """
    time.sleep(.5)
    print """ \ \ \     """
    time.sleep(.5)
    print """  \ \ \   """
    time.sleep(.5)
    print """   \ \/   """
    time.sleep(.5)
    print """    \/\   """
    time.sleep(.5)
    print """    /\/   """
    time.sleep(.5)
    print """   / /\       """
    time.sleep(.5)
    print """  / / /     """
    time.sleep(.5)
    print """ / / /      """
    time.sleep(.5)
    proceed1234 = raw_input("| | |")
    if proceed1234 == "q":
        main_menu()
    elif proceed1234 == "b":
        animations1()
    else:
        time.sleep(.5)
        bi2()
def play2():#2nd built in
    print "Type in 'q' at any time possible to return to the main menu, or 'b' to go to     the animations menu."
    bi2()
def bi1():
    print "    |   "
    time.sleep(.5)
    print "    |"
    time.sleep(.5)
    print """   /\"""
    time.sleep(.5)
    print '''  /  \'''
    time.sleep(.5)
    print " | OO |"
    time.sleep(.5)
    print '''  \  /'''
    time.sleep(.5)
    print '''   \/'''
    time.sleep(.5)
    print "    |"
    proceed123 = raw_input("    |")
    if proceed123 == "q":
        main_menu()
    elif proceed123 == "b":
        animations1()
else:
        time.sleep(.5)
        bi1()
def play1(): #first built in animation
    print "Type in 'q' at any time possible to return to the main menu, or 'b' to go to     the animations menu."
    bi1()
def animations1(): #pre made animations
    print "You are now viewing the pre-made animations."
    time.sleep(1)
    print "During each animation, hold down enter for the animation to play, or type     'q' then enter to quit."
    time.sleep(1)
    animation_choice = raw_input("Type in '1' for animation 1, '2' for animation 2, or     'q' to go back to the main menu.: ")
    if animation_choice1 == "1":
        play1()
    elif animation_choice1 == "2":
        play2()
    elif animation_choice1 == "q":
        main_menu()
    else:
        print "Invalid choice, check spelling and try again."
        animations1()
def main_menu():
    print "Type in 'q' to quit the program."
    print "Type in 'v1' to choose between 2 pre-made animations."
    print "Type in 'as' to go to the animation studio."
    print "Type in 'v2' to view your custom animations."
    choice = raw_input("Or type in 'b' to go back to the explaination of this program.:     ")
    if choice == "b":
        explaination()
    elif choice == v1:
        animations1() #animations1 is the pre-made one
    elif choice == "as":
        animation_studio()
    elif choice == "v2":
        animations2() #animations2 is the custom user-made animations
    elif choice == "q":
        quitcheck = raw_input("Are you sure you would like to exit the program?     (type 'y' or 'n'): ")
        if quitcheck == "y":
            print "Goodbye."
            time.sleep(2)
        elif quitcheck == "n":
            main_menu()
        else:
            print "Invalid choice (check spelling/case), returning to main menu    ..."
            time.sleep(1)
            main_menu()
    else:
        print "Invalid choice, please check your spelling and try again."
        main_menu()

def explaination():
    print "Welcome to the animation viewer/maker!"
    time.sleep(1)
    print "In the main menu, you can select what you would like to do."
    time.sleep(1)
    print "This program uses text characters to animate something in a loop."
    time.sleep(1)
    print "As long as you don't close this program, it can save 2 different custom     animations, and you can view the ones you created or the pre-made ones."
    time.sleep(1)
    print "With custom animations, you can type anything you want to create animations     that loop (see the pre-made ones for ideas/examples). They can be up to 10 lines."
    time.sleep(1)
    jafsdlk = raw_input("Please press enter to continue.: ")
    main_menu() 
explaination()
```

i may have copied the code wrong but i dont know.
anyway, iu havent added the animation studio yet or the ability to make and save custom animations, and its a pretty simple type of program.
but when i put this in notepad and save it as a .py file and run it to test it, i start getting an error when it runs explaination(), it says it has an error with triple quoted strings, but if i make the triple quoted strings with one quote, it gives me EOL while scanning literal, someone help

Comment: Please say more about the error that you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash `\` is an escape character. You typically use it so Python will take the next character literally.

You can prefix the string with `r` to indicate a raw string or surround it with triple quotes, as you've done. However, you're running into problems with the `\` escaping the first `"` in the close triple-quote of your line, which makes three quotes to open it, and only two to close--which makes it seek out the next `"`, in the next line, which throws off everything else.

Right:

```
print r"This works because there's a space after the slash \ "
```

Wrong:

```
print r"This doesn't \"
```

https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals